# How to check if service is running before installation?

Tags: service, wix

I'd like to check if some service is running on the local computer before installation of my product. How can I check it?

Comment: Installed, or running? What happens if it's running when you check, but not running later when *action X* (whatever requires it) executes?

Comment: This is a licensing service which must be running before installing software. If it is not installed it can be installed later, no problem. I'd like to show warning to user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done through a custom action. With custom code you can find any information you want about a service. That information can then be saved in installer properties which can be used during install.

Since you need access to installer properties, you will have to use a win32 DLL or VBScript custom action. You can find a C++ DLL custom action tutorial here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/msicustomaction.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using WiX, you can use CloseApplication in WixUtilExtension to do this. Set @RebootPrompt="no" since you *want* it to be running and not shut down. Set @Property to a property you then use in a condition to show your warning.